# The kamma of silence and/or "not acting"?

Tags: personal-practice, karma, ethics, sila

Aside of Silas there is the matter of kamma which includes always the mind.

What's the impact of acting "political correct" or "according to laws", Sila, while having unskilful intentions?

Whould breaking Silas be possible when mind is skilful adjusted?

May skilful acting look like unskilful?

What's the impact of your surpressing a honest answer, well considered, here, while possible having unskilful thoughts an reasons to act so? Or simply guided by not knowing, ignorance?

Of cause it could be that one is limited by circumstances or "forced" to "lie" to fulfill contracts, but what should then be actually given up, left behind?

(It's of less support to answer in manners of ultimate, because even not possible, and does not help in getting started with basics and home tasks, but are purely speculations of defilements: excuses to act proper and to investigate one mind and intentions honest.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the Sangha primarily exists to maintain the Noble Dhamma in the world for those few who search for liberation from the world.

When the world becomes rotten to the core, such as the American and most governments, and when these governments become totalitarian (which is gradually occurring), for bhikkhus to criticize these governments may endanger the Sangha and the maintenance of the Dhamma.

Ultimately, the Dhamma is lokuttara. Ultimately, the Buddha did not arise in the world to teach about kamma, worldly sila or sīlabbata-parāmāsa.

'Kamma' is not actually a teaching of the Buddhas. The Buddhas teach
 the following:

> *Bhikkhus, this Dhamma taught by me is unrefuted, undefiled, irreproachable, and uncensured by wise ascetics and brahmins. And what
>   is the Dhamma taught by me that is unrefuted, undefiled,
>   irreproachable, and uncensured by wise ascetics and brahmins?*
>
> *‘These are the **six elements**’: this, bhikkhus, is the Dhamma taught by me that is unrefuted … uncensured by wise ascetics and brahmins.
>   ‘These are the **six bases for contact**’ … ‘These are the **eighteen mental
>   examinations**’ … ‘These are the **four noble truths**’: this, bhikkhus, is
>   the Dhamma taught by me that is unrefuted, undefiled, irreproachable
>   and uncensured by wise ascetics and brahmins.*
>
> *AN 3.61*

'Kamma' teachings the Buddha said are defiled with attachment, as follows:

> *And what is the right view with effluents, siding with merit, resulting in acquisitions? 'There is what is given, what is offered,
>   what is sacrificed. There are fruits & results of good & bad actions.
>   There is this world & the other world.*
>
> *MN 117*

Kamma is this world & the other world; where as Nibbana is not this world & not another world.